# Definition of Normal Subgroup to be used while proving that a given subgroup is Normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have seen these two definitions in Herstein.

1. N is a normal subgroup of G iff $gNg^{-1} \subset N$ for all g $\in G$
2. N is a normal subgroup of G iff $gNg^{-1} = N$ for all g $\in G$

Later in problem set, I came across an example where we had $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ but $gHg^{-1}$ $\neq H$ for a subgroup $H$. Here, $H$ is normal or not?

I am confused between the two definitions, first one is automatically true if second is true.

Comment: What is that example? The inner automorphism $gxg^{-1}$ should be bijective.

Comment: For a fixed $g$ it is perfectly possible to have $gHg^{-1}$ be a proper subgroup of $H$.  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401592/normal-subgroup-if-conjugate-subgroup-is-subset) describes an example.  Keep in mind, however, that this is for a particular $g\in G$.

Comment: In the example you saw the condition was for a single element $g\in G$ rather than for all $g\in G$. That subgroup is not normal.  But the two definitions of normal subgroup are equivalent because those conditions are for all $g\in G$.

Comment: @player3236 the group might be infinite. so it can happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions $1$ and $2$ are equivalent. (Note:  I am assuming that $1$ ought to read $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$).

It is clear that $2\implies 1$.

To see that $1\implies 2$:  choose $n\in N$.  Then $n=gg^{-1}ngg^{-1}$ But $g^{-1}ng\in N$ by assumption, so we are done.

To stress:  it is crucial that $1$ hold $\textit {for all }g\in G$. In the above, for example, we assumed it held for both $g, g^{-1}$.